# Granite devices IONI servo drive

Tags: servomotor

The IONI drive can accept a new setpoint using an analog input.  How many bits is the ADC on the IONI drive?  Is it 12, or 16 bit?

Answer (score 2):

Although the [Analog setpoint](https://granitedevices.com/wiki/Analog_setpoint) resolution isn't documented on the [Granite Devices Wiki](https://granitedevices.com/wiki/IONI_Servo_%26_Stepper_Drive), the ADC in IONI is 12 bits.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Granite Devices. It's always good to see manufacturers on here but please read [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and [How not to be a spammer](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Also, on Stack Exchange we are are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Generally speaking one-line answers with no references cannot do this, so answers which don't include explanations may be removed (or in your case voted down by someone). For such a simple question your simple answer is ok, however I have added links back to relevant pages on your wiki to help future readers of your answer. You may want to consider updating your wiki with the ADC resolution though.